# Weird behavior of LinearGradientBrush

Tags: c#, winforms, system.drawing, brush, lineargradientbrush

I want to fill a Rectangle with a LinearGradientBrush. With some Rectangles I get some strange behavior. Example:

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle( 20, 20, 20, 34 );
LinearGradientMode mode = LinearGradientMode.Vertical;
Brush brush = new LinearGradientBrush( rect, Color.White, Color.Blue, mode );
e.Graphics.FillRectangle( brush, rect );
```

Most Rectangles work OK, but some (like the one above) fill the first pixel row with the second color (blue in this case).
See attached image:

[image: Linear GradientBrush]

Any ideas?

Comment: A later, better answer was posted here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8015656/gdi-net-lineargradientbrush-wider-than-202-pixels-causes-color-wrap-around

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the brush one pixel taller:

```
LinearGradientMode mode = LinearGradientMode.Vertical;
Rectangle BrushRect = rect;
BrushRect.Inflate(0, 1);
Brush brush = new LinearGradientBrush(BrushRect, Color.White, Color.Blue, mode);
```

Comment: Good idea. That fixes it. But do you know why it happens at all?

Answer (score 2):

Problem is the bug in MS implementation of Fill():
When you think you take brush and apply at some point (X,Y), **MS** works from opposite side: they take Y offset and count **remainder** from division on brush height. That reminder becomes offset inside a brush to take a color. In other words the canvas where you paint become "tiled" with your brush with absolute offset 0. So if you paint gradient at position Y=7, color for  gradient also taken (from brush) at offset 7 (instead of 0)!