# GDI+ .NET: LinearGradientBrush wider than 202 pixels causes color wrap-around

Tags: .net, winforms, graphics, gdi+

If i paint a rectangle that is wider than 202 pixels wide with a `LinearGradientBrush`, i get a color fringe on the left:

[image]

Given the code for a **202px** wide rectangle:

```
private void MainForm_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
   Rectangle r = new Rectangle(50, 50, 202, 50);

   Color color1 = Color.FromArgb(unchecked((int)0xFF00024d));
   Color color2 = Color.FromArgb(unchecked((int)0xFFd6a20f));

   Brush b = new LinearGradientBrush(r, color1, color2, LinearGradientMode.Horizontal);
   e.Graphics.FillRectangle(b, r);
}
```

i get a rectangle that paints correctly:

[image]

But if i change the rectangle to be **203** pixels wide:

```
Rectangle r = new Rectangle(50, 50, 203, 50);
```

The rectangle has a color fringe, or wrap-around, on the left:

[image]

---

It also happens in the vertical direction with `LinearGradientMode.Vertical`:

**202px**:

[image]

**203px**:

[image]

Comment: Reproducible here too. Looks like a bug.

Comment: ILSpy only tells me that all the interesting stuff seems to be happening inside gdiplus.dll.

Comment: This is to remind you to accept answers you are happy with. You are well aware of the site, so this probably slipped through the cracks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add this statement before the FillRectangle() call:

```
 e.Graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.Half;
```

That avoids off-by-one problems due to floating point rounding error.

Comment: This works perfectly. Based on the documentation ("*Specifies that pixels are offset by -.5 units, both horizontally and vertically*") i was concerned that the pixels might be offset by -.5 units. Fortunately `PixelOffsetMode.Half` doesn't offset the pixels by half, and everything renders as it should.