# FillPath with LinearGradientBrush

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, graphics, drawing

I found a similar problem from this topic [GDI+ .NET: LinearGradientBrush wider than 202 pixels causes color wrap-around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8015656/gdi-net-lineargradientbrush-wider-than-202-pixels-causes-color-wrap-around)
But the solution didn't work for me. I cannot ask in that topic as well. Please take a look. Here is my code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {

    int ShadowThick = 10;
    Color ShadowColor = Color.Gray;
    int width;
    int height;

    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        width = this.Width - 100;
        height = this.Height - 100;
    }

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
        //e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        GraphicsPath shadowPath = new GraphicsPath();
        LinearGradientBrush shadowBrush = null;
        // draw vertical shadow
        shadowPath.AddArc(this.width - this.ShadowThick, this.ShadowThick, this.ShadowThick,
            this.ShadowThick, 180, 180);
        shadowPath.AddLine(this.width, this.ShadowThick * 2, this.width,
            this.height - this.ShadowThick);
        shadowPath.AddLine(this.width, this.height - this.ShadowThick,
            this.width - this.ShadowThick, this.height - this.ShadowThick);
        shadowPath.CloseFigure();
        // declare the brush
        shadowBrush = new LinearGradientBrush(PointF.Empty,
            new PointF(this.ShadowThick + 1, 0), this.ShadowColor, Color.Transparent);
        //shadowBrush = new LinearGradientBrush(PointF.Empty,
        //    new PointF(this.ShadowThick + 1, 0), this.ShadowColor, Color.Transparent);

        //e.Graphics.DrawPath(Pens.Black, shadowPath);

        e.Graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.Half;
        e.Graphics.FillPath(shadowBrush, shadowPath);
    }

}
```

I want it dark to light from left to right, but see:

[image]

I am trying to draw a shadow and I stuck at this.

Comment: You didn't ask a question.  What is the result you are expecting that you aren't getting?

Comment: The above code fill gradient not correctly. Run the code and you will see. The problem is like the topic in the link I included.

Comment: I did run it and I don't see any issue.  That's why I asked for you to offer more information.  Link some screen shots if need be.

Comment: I've just update a screenshot, please take a look at the link. Sorry I cannot post image yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Hans commented below, the brush coordinates need to match the path, so instead of this:

```
shadowBrush = new LinearGradientBrush(PointF.Empty,
    new PointF(this.ShadowThick + 1, 0), this.ShadowColor, Color.Transparent);
```

it should be:

```
new LinearGradientBrush(new Point(this.width - this.ShadowThick, 0),
                        new Point(this.width, 0),
                        this.ShadowColor, Color.Transparent);
```

Also, you should dispose of the graphic objects you create.  I also changed your brush to just use Point instead of PointF since you aren't dealing with floating numbers.

Here is your code re-written:

```
  e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
  e.Graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.Half;
  using (GraphicsPath shadowPath = new GraphicsPath()) {
    shadowPath.StartFigure();
    shadowPath.AddArc(this.width - this.ShadowThick, this.ShadowThick, 
        this.ShadowThick, this.ShadowThick, 180, 180);
    shadowPath.AddLine(this.width, this.ShadowThick * 2, this.width,
        this.height - this.ShadowThick);
    shadowPath.AddLine(this.width, this.height - this.ShadowThick,
        this.width - this.ShadowThick, this.height - this.ShadowThick);
    shadowPath.CloseFigure();
    using (var shadowBrush = new LinearGradientBrush(
        new Point(this.width - this.ShadowThick, 0),
        new Point(this.width, 0),
        this.ShadowColor, Color.Transparent)) {
      e.Graphics.FillPath(shadowBrush, shadowPath);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Yours is off as well, just one pixel.  The OP's mistake is that he assumed that the points passed to the brush constructor are relative.  They are absolute.  Just fix the brush constructor to start at new Point(this.width - this.ShadowTick, 0) instead of Point.Empty.  And end at this.width.